# Run Laravel Dusk on multiple web domains

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I have multiple websites.

1. en.web-site.com/pages/faqs
2. fr.web-site.com/pages/faqs
3. ar.web-site.com/pages/faqs
4. br.web-site.com/pages/faqs
5. ... 30 more websites that have the same URI structure

I want to run a browser test on each of these websites.

I've updated the emails on the faqs pages of all my websites and I want to test if all of them have the changes.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;

class UpdatedEmailTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function testUpdatedEmail()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/pages/faqs')
                ->assertPathIs('/pages/faqs')
                ->assertSee('new_email@sample.com')
                ->assertDontSee('old_email@sample.com');
        });
    }
}
```

This test will absolutely work fine on any of my websites, but I have to edit the `.env` file every time I have to run it.

What can I do that will allow me to test on all of these websites without having to edit the `.env` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you may need a loop over all the 30+ website domains.

```
public function testUpdatedEmail()
{
    $websites = .... //array with full urls and emails

    foreach ($websites as $website)

      $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($website) {
          $browser->visit($website["url"])
            ->assertPathIs(parse_url($website["url"], PHP_URL_PATH))
            ->assertSee($website["new_email"])
            ->assertDontSee($website["old_email"]);
    });
}
```

Refer to Browers.php https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/bcb05e6fe29817bbf04574f68996312a296bb366/src/Browser.php#L119